# how to start automatically Ubuntu Update Manager / Ubuntu Software Centre downloads on a particular time of day

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

How do I automatically start Ubuntu Update Manager on a particular time of the day and make it download updates ?

Similarly, do I automatically update installed softwares (Ubuntu Software Center) on a particular time of the day and make downloads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install cron-apt:

> sudo apt-get install cron-apt

Edit config-file:

> sudo gedit /etc/cron.d/cron-apt

comment the line: (put '#' in front of it)

> 0 0 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/cron-apt && /usr/sbin/cron-apt

Add these lines to the end of the file:

Every day (midnight)

> 0 0 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/cron-apt && /usr/sbin/cron-apt

Save the file.

For more information see:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Answer (score 5):

You can either set apt-get to update and upgrade in cron.daily or you could simply use cron-apt. There is also an unattended-upgrades package but I haven't used it.

Unless there is a reason that you only want to work with the Ubuntu Update-Manager/Software-Center, although I can't see why.

It's an issue that has been answered in various locations, so here are some references:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates/
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

  - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692253
- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/162

Comment: What is the command to start the Update Manager and to tell to install? What is the command to start the automatic update in software center installed software?

Comment: I am trying to use 'Schedule tasks' downloaded from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Software Center.

Comment: @gladiator2345 I appreciate Astyanax's answer. But I was looking for specific instructions like I have put in my answer today. After following the answer by Astyanax,which was very helpful to find the solution, but I struggled to get the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [unattended upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html). While that doesn't say anything about when they will take place, another good howto can be found [here](http://www.shaolintiger.com/2012/03/15/running-unattendedautomatic-security-updates-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts-lucid/) which works without additional software, and to me looks more like a direct answer to your question. Though you might want to substitute the cron-part from "daily" to something more precise. You might heck this [Cron Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) for details on how to handle that.